# Setting the input type with css or javascript

Tags: javascript, css, forms, html

I have several checkboxes on my page in a div called OPTIONS.  like this

```
<div id="options">     
<input type="checkbox"..... > 
<input type="checkbox"..... >
<input type="checkbox"..... >
<input type="checkbox"..... >
<input type="checkbox"..... >
...
...
</div>
```

Since I know every input in this div will always be a checkbox, I was wondering if there's a way in css or javascript to make them automatically be checkboxes without me typing `type="checkbox"` each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just do this in JavaScript like so:

```
var inputs = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("input"));
inputs.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
})
```

This converts the NodeList of `<input>` elements into an array which then sets the `type` attribute.

Here’s a jQuery/ES6 way of doing it too:

```
$("input").each(elem => elem.attr("type", "checkbox"))
```

Comment: This looks good, but how can I make it so it only effects inputs in the options div?

Comment: Oh, I figured it out, change to... `document.getElementById('options').getElementsByTagName("input")`

Comment: Yep @CheeseFlavored that’s it, sorry I didn’t include that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Setting in the html will be better option. By default input type is `text` and changing the type through javascript will be a slower process then setting it directly in html

If you still opt to do that you can target the element , get it's children and then loop over it and change the type using `setAttribute`

`document.getElementById('options').children` will give a collection, using spread operator `...` so that array method can be used

```js
[...document.getElementById('options').children].forEach(item => {
  item.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox')

})
```

```html
<div id="options">
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#options input');
  
  for(let input of inputs) {
    console.log(input);
    input.type = 'checkbox';
  }

});
```

```html
<div id="options">     
<input> 
<input>
<input>
<input>
<input>
<input> 
<input>
<input>
<input>
<input><input> 
<input>
<input>
<input>
<input><input> 
<input>
<input>
<input>
<input><input> 
<input>
<input>
<input>
<input>
</div>
```